# Recently Android studio 2.2 - Unable to drag views around in layout file

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I updated to 2.2 literaly 30 minutes ago and when I tried to move widgets around in layouts,

this happened:

https://gyazo.com/d3c640cca6f212aaa9effe2db9bccb98

I can't center it or even move it to the right,center,etc. It's always stuck on the left.

What's wrong with it? any ideas? should I uninstall Android Studio and re-install it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Should Post your layout.xml file here, But i think you should go and change the layout in the layout file from linerlayout to the Relative Layout .

Linear Layout puts widgets one after the other.

Relative Layout puts stuff or widgets relative to the other widgets on the page or the relative things like centre of the page or 5dp below another widget.

Hope it helps :)